# Laravel - How to get column created_at without hours

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to list a couple of records and I just want to show y-m-d of `created_at` , not hours.

I'm doing this in query:

```
$letter = Letter::select('letters.id', DB::raw('DATE(letters.created_at) created_at'), 'letters.userId')
                    ->where('letters.active', '=', 1)
                    ->where('letters.userId', '=', $user->id)
                    ->paginate(20);
```

But returns me this column like this `2017-08-30 00:00:00`

How can I solve that?

Thank you

Comment: How is the dates saved in the database? UNIX?

Comment: you can make use of getXXXAttribute() function on your model if you need it quite usually... and return something like return $this->created_at->format('d/m/Y');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make query like this to format date in laravel

```
 ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT("letters.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as new_date', 'letters.id', 'letters.userId')
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to Carbon/DateTime object and [format it](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)

Comment: It's good to use carbon but it should be secondary option. First try filter/format by database query.